# How to map a JavaDstream object into a string? Spark Streaming and Model Prediction JAVA

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am very new at spark world and just started programing java 6 months ago. So I am having difficult:

```
   JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(
            new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
                public Iterable<String> call(String x) {
                    return Arrays.asList(x.split(","));
                }
            });
    words.print(); String vec = words;
```

I would like to transform this JavaDStream into a string. Because after i will be able to use it as an input to my model! I beleave I should use the foreachRDD method to accomplish...

```
        Double predictionDone = sameModel.predict(Vectors.dense(vec));
        System.out.println(predictionDone.toString());
```

Comment: I suggest you go through the Spark Streaming docs in depth to gain the foundations you need in order to  apply it: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html

Comment: Im doing it thx, I have 2 pieces but i cannot connect them... I can open a stream and i can also load a model and do predictions

Comment: I added a broad answer to help you in your way, but you will need to pick up on a lot of material. If you are starting with Java I suggest you to jump to  Scala instead. Will help you understand the functional aspects much better.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is not how to map a DStream object into a String, but how to score the values contained in the DStream at each streaming interval.
A DStream is a time-bound collection of RDDs. You can work on DStream by applying high level operations to it. Within Spark those operations  are applied to RDD built at each interval with the data available at that time.

Instead of thinking "how to go from DStream to String", the right path is "how to access the elements of the DStream and apply my scoring function to them".

In broad lines, you need few steps:

-First, construct your stream, using one of the [supported DStream implementations](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#input-dstreams-and-receivers) (or roll your own):

```
 JavaDStream<String> textDStream = ...
```

-Apply [transformations](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#transformations-on-dstreams) to get the data in the shape you require it:

```
 JavaDStream<String> wordsDStream = textDStream.flatMap(...).filter(...)
```

-Once you have the data in the right shape, you need to apply an [output operation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams) to the DStream in order to actually do something with the data. `foreachRDD` is the most generic output operator, that allows us to apply [actions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions) to the underlying RDDs.

```
wordsDStream.foreachRDD{rdd =>  // here we get access to the RDD
    rdd.foreach{word =>   // here we get access to the content of the RDD, 
                          // which is the 'words' in the DStream
       val score = model.score(word)
       // do something with 'score' like write it to a db or file
    }
 }
```

(this is scala pseudo-code. In Java the structure is the same. Only the code is more verbose)

In rough lines this is the structure to follow. Combining the ML model adds some level of complexity which can be challenging.

Answer (score 0):

```
    words.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaRDD<String>, Void>() {
        public Void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {
            if(rdd!=null)
            {
                List<String> result = rdd.collect();
                double[] d = new double[69]; // model input expected lenght
                int i=0;


                for (String temp : result) {
                    double aDouble = Double.parseDouble(temp);
                    d[i]=aDouble; i++;
                    list_transactions.add(Vectors.dense(d)); //global variable

                }
            }
            return null;
```

Here is the solution! It works

@maasg, thx for the help! "how to access the elements of the DStream and apply my scoring function to them" this was the key to what i was looking for!